# Keras : How can I transform my data in order to fit for this specific Deep Learning architecture?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

Let's say that my training data is a 3d numpy array with dimensions (4155, 5, 150). This data consists of 4155 training samples, each one featuring a 5*150 matrix, while my labels are 4155. I then want to feed it to the following architecture :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(input_dim=4,
input_length=1000,
nb_filter=320,
filter_length=26,
border_mode="valid",
activation="relu",
subsample_length=1))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=13, stride=13))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(brnn)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(input_dim=75*640, output_dim=925))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=925, output_dim=919))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

The problem is that a) I don't know how to change the dimensionality of my input array, so that it can fit to this model. The above specified layer parameters are just for the example. I simply want to use a Convolutional Layer, followed by a Bidirrectional LSTM and finally two Fully Connected Layers. Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The doc (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) is quite clear: Input shape - 3D tensor with shape: (samples, steps, input_dim). Assuming your input has the correct shape, your input_dim should be 150.